# remove readonly from input

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, bootstrap-4

I have a pice of code that copy 2 3 divs and the div contains a readonly property.

After that I have a button that says to edit when I click on that button this should remove the readonly and the input field is available to edit.

My code that doesn't work!

my javascript code:

I have tried `removeAttr`, `prop('readonly', false)`, `attr('readonly', false)`

```
  $("body").on("click", ".btn",function(){ 
        if($(this).is("#edit")){
         $(this).parents(".control-group").removeAttr('readonly');
        }else if($(this).is("#save")){

        }else if($(this).is("#remove")){
          $(this).parents(".control-group").remove();
    }
  });
```

The div that I copy:

```
<div class="control-group input-group" style="margin-top:10px">
  <input id="rule" type="text" class="form-control" readonly>
  <div class="input-group-btn">
    <button id="edit" class="btn btn-danger remove" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> Edit</button><button id="remove" class="btn btn-danger remove" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> Remove</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope that when i click on edit the readonly disappear and after a click on save and the readonly back again.

Thanks for the help

PS: the remove button works!

Comment: wtf stackslave?? the input had a default readonly i only whant to know how to remove and add the "readonly" with jquery or javascript or other whay that i don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have better luck with `.attr` as `readonly` is an `attribute` and not a `property`. See [this](https://api.jquery.com/prop/) (Specifically, **attributes vs properties**)

One issue I see with your code is this line here:
`$(this).parents(".control-group").removeAttr('readonly');`

You are trying to remove the readonly attribute from a `div`. I think you mean to remove it from your `.form-control` which is an `input`

Maybe try `$(this).parents(".control-group").find('input.form-control').removeAttr('readonly');` (i'd do some null checks here. Plenty can go wrong if the selector fails)

Here's a basic example of how to toggle the `readonly` attribute using jQuery

```js
var readonly = true;
$('button').on('click', (e) => {
  readonly = !readonly
  $('input').attr('readonly', readonly);
  // Extra
  if (readonly) {
    $('input').attr('placeholder', "I'm readonly");
  } else {
    $('input').attr('placeholder', "I'm not readonly");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input readonly placeholder="I'm readonly" />
<button>Toggle Readonly</button>
```

Comment: I updated my answer. But, you essentially are removing readonly from the wrong element

Answer (score 0):

You're applying `remove` to the wrong element.

Try this:

```
$("body").on("click", ".btn",function(){ 
    if($(this).is("#edit")){
        $(this).parents(".control-group").find('input').removeAttr('readonly');
        }
        ...
    }
});
```

Using the `find` jQuery function, you can call every input element inside the `.control-group` element. To further expand the functionality, say, to include `select` elements or other buttons (with a `unlock-readonly` class, for instance), you can try:

```
$(this).parents(".control-group").find('input, select, .unlock-readonly').removeAttr('readonly');
```